# Rotate service accounts with Vault in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hashicorp-vault

I'm in process of implementing Vault in my organization. We run our services on GCP on compute engine instances as docker containers.

Each compute node can run multiple services and hence we use JSON Service Accounts Keys to auth against other google services (Dataproc, Google Cloud Storage etc.).

One of the challenge that we are facing right now is that we generate these json keys using terraform and are baked into the machines when infrastructure is getting provisioned.

Once provisioned these keys lives on forever, which is a bad way to handling the keys as if any key get compromised then we are at high risk.

To reduce the surface area, we are planning to have key rotation in place for which we are looking into vault. Vault will also help us have centralized secrets (instead of secrets in gitlab variables) and dynamic database credentials for MySQL.

While reading Vault's documentation the Vault's architecture is as follows.

1. You authenticate with vault using a service account.
2. Based on membership of the service account in a group you have different policies assigned to you.
3. Those policies have role-sets based on which ephemeral service accounts are generated.
4. You use the ephemeral service account which has a lease and can be revoked centrally.

Now from what I understand, you need a service account to authenticate with vault, so that you can get service account from Vault. This seemed to me like a chicken and egg problem.

I want a service account from vault, but to get that I need a service account to authenticate.

So how will I get my first service account ? Lets say I bake in the first service accounts via Terraform ? I couldn't find a way to rotate them ?

Am I missing something in my understanding of Vault ?

Comment: Where is running your Vault? On GCP?

Comment: Where are you running your code? If in GCP, then use default service accounts which removed the need to the service account JSON key file. Hashicorp vault has many authentication methods. One method is to use a token. Store that token in Google Secrets Manager. If you use Google service accounts assigned to compute services you then do not need to worry about rotating the service account keys. Google will manage the service account for you. For more ideas read this link: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/gcp